# Exporting iPod Touch library

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I have an iPod Touch 4th generation running on iOS 4. For various reasons, I don't have a copy of all my songs on my computer running Windows 7 with iTunes 11. Is there a way to export my whole library, which contains both songs purchased on iTunes and songs ripped from CDs, to iTunes or elsewhere on my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only means I have ever found of doing this is third-party software. I have used Senuti for this, and can confirm that it works.

The current version of Senuti: http://www.fadingred.com/senuti/. The free trial version allows you to restore up to 1000 songs. There is also a fully-free version from 2008 [MD5 (Senuti.0.52.dmg) = e84ebf4614ded95c53dc750492297c87] at http://wstein.org/senuti/, but though the source code is available (there and at SourceForge), it has not been maintained, and I have *not* confirmed that it still works.
(You can [get an older version from the developer](http://www.fadingred.com/files/senuti/senuti_0.50.5.dmg), too.)

There is also TouchCopy: http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy. It appears to be very complete but is expensive, and the trial version is more limiting than is that of Senuti.

Comment: Re the fully free version: He DOES now have the source code.  However, when I tried the free version on my 10.8.5 Mac, it crashed on launch.  Is it working for anyone?

Comment: @MatthewElvey I haven’t tried it, but from the screenshot now on that page, the version for which he has source code was released in 2008, and OS X 10.8 was released four years after that. I imagine that perhaps a Mac developer might be able to bring it up to date given the code, but as it is I wouldn’t expect it to run on 10.8.

Comment: Agreed.  The free version did work recently, per this month-old article: http://www.iskysoft.com/topic-ipod/transfer-ipod-songs-and-videos-to-mac-with-senuti.html so I would say it's hardly confirmed that it doesn't work on 10.8.  I'll try it on a clean OS (I have one fairly handy for that) and 10.6 (ditto).  Updating your answer.

Comment: @MatthewElvey Thanks for the edits — they are now in the answer (albeit themselves edited). :)

Answer (score 0):

I have heard very good reviews of [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) and it is designed to do exactly what you seek. I use [Phoneview](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to get at things as I don't need the extra functionality of iExplorer and Phoneview was for sale when I was buying a tool for this a few years back.